# Use of Blend over VS2012?

Tags: windows-8

I wonder what is the purpose  of Blend in windows8 app development.
What is specific purpose of having Blend Blend with VS?
What can be done by Blend that cannot be by VS?

Comment: what a great question. msft should be admonished for selling it.

Comment: @DrewPierce Blend is part of Visual Studio now

Comment: @JimO'Neil well hopefully they cleaned up their act. used to be you were better off with notepad and xaml than thinking that tool could modify a canvas

Answer (score 2):

[This link at the Windows Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj129478.aspx) should help. In a nutshell, Blend has more of a designer focused mindset and better tooling for doing things like animations and dealing with visual states.  For HTML/JS it has some even more compelling features like [interactive mode](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/DevRadio/Microsoft-DevRadio-Part-3-Using-Blend-to-Help-Design-Your-Windows-8-AppsInteractive-Mode).

In the end though, Blend helps you craft XAML and CSS, so do you "need" it no, but if you prefer to style your applications and objects with visual feedback versus tinkering in the bowels of 100's of lines of XAML, it's worth being somewhat familiar with it. :)

Comment: I would also add that Blend has better support if you're using Storyboards and Visual States to control your UI.